# Can I upgrade ghostscript from source on 10.04 over existing gs version 8.71?

Tags: 10.04, ghostscript

I would like to upgrade to a newer version of ghostscript (latest is 9.05, but anything in the 9.x series). Can I **build and install from source** over the top of the existing install?

I had a dry-run of uninstalling current version, but there were a lot of other things that would be removed with it that I didn't want to remove (for example freenx??).